# How to get this sorting work in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

I have column values like `A1,A20........A10.` When I do an order by, the values are displayed as `A1,A10, A2` and so on...

But, I want to display the columns in this format

```
A1
A2
A10
A20 and so on..
```

Can someone please tell me how do I achieve this sorting?

Comment: Do all the values begin with one letter? Or can there be multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the pattern of your column is just A-Z + some numbers, you could sort with

```
select id
  from your_table
 order by regexp_replace(id, '[0-9]', ''), 
          to_number(regexp_replace(upper(id), '[A-Z]', ''));
```

`regexp_replace(id, '[0-9]', ''),`

the above just keeps "A"s first, then "B" etc. you can remove that if you don't want to do that.

but if any row has any other non-numeric characters, the query would fail on invalid number.

eg:

```
SQL> select * from tester order by id;

ID
-----
A1
A10
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
B1
B10
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
B9

20 rows selected.

SQL> select id from tester order by regexp_replace(id, '[0-9]', ''), to_number(regexp_replace(upper(id), '[A-Z]', ''));

ID
-----
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
A10
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
B9
B10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach from Ask Tom:

```
select x from t
order by decode(sign(ascii(substr(lpad(x, 2), 2))-64), 1,
                lpad(x, 3, chr(58)),
                lpad(x, 2));
```

[link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:786026162431#7960923350503)